# Git hook management

Tags: git

Currently using [husky](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/) for node based project and [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) for python based one.

I like the fact that `husky` is installed as a dependency and `pre-commit` for being fairly language agnostic.

I am looking for a recommendation for a git hook manager alternative to both/either that would provide: installation as dependency and being language agnostic.

Comment: This question is extremely confusing - alternative for what? Husky, pre-commit, both, other language/framework? Why do you need an alternative if you're looking for the same capabilities?

Comment: I am looking for recommendation for git hook manager.